# How can I convert a stereo (two channels) audio file to a mono (one channel) audio file in iOS?

Tags: ios, audio, avfoundation, apple-watch, avaudioengine

Currently, I'm recording audio on the Apple Watch using the presentAudioRecorderController and sending it to the corresponding iPhone app.

The audio format by default seems to be recorded on the Apple Watch using two channels and there doesn't seem to be a way to change that.

For various reasons, I need the audio format to be only one channel. I was hoping there would be something on iOS to convert the audio file from stereo (two channels) to mono (one channel)

Right now, I'm investigating if this is possible using AVAudioEngine and other various related classes. I'm not sure if it's possible and it seems very complicated at the moment.

Comment: Did you ever find a workaround for this? I'm struggling with a similar situation at them moment.